# What does "I stayed in my body" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[On Twitter](https://twitter.com/CBSNews/status/1376977598518075395), CBS summarizes one of their articles (bolding mine):

> In a tense exchange, bystander Donald Williams pushed back when the [sic] Derek Chauvin's attorney asked whether he grew more and more angry with Chauvin during the fatal arrest of George Floyd.
> "**I stayed in my body**. You can't paint me out to be angry."

What does "I stayed in my body" mean here? From context it seems it might mean something like "I stayed calm", but I'm not sure if that catches all the nuances?

Googling, I don't get many hits on the phrase, besides the news item - is this an uncommon phrase?

Comment: I think you are right. I parse it as "I remained composed" or "I was able to control/restrain my emotions".

Comment: You don't get many hits because the usage has no currency. Of the three written instances of [***"I stayed in my body"***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+stayed+in+my+body%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01wKhuUCNslRuQp2BdCkFu4TbPf2g:1617194913047&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW9cvCyNrvAhUO_7sIHVCwC50QpwUIJg&biw=1520&bih=706&dpr=1.25) in Google Books, one has "in" in "scare quotes" (implying the writer knows it's a non-standard usage), and one seems to be a sci-fi context where people can switch between different bodies.

Comment: Yes, it is uncommon. In fact, I've never heard of it until now. If you don't get many hits, then that means it's uncommon.

Comment: Perhaps you are expecting a literal definition. speaker is speaking in conceptual terms. Consider the phrase 'acting out' one's frustration' as the antithesis

Comment: **This is just creative expression**, not everything people say has already been said. However, we do say: jump out of one's skin. So, if you don't jump out of your skin, you are actually "staying in your body". So, actually, he's very creative with language! I wonder how any of the posters do when reading novels....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phrase is based in Cultural Somatics - see *My Grandmother's Hands: Racialized Trauma and the Pathway to Mending Our Hearts and Bodies* by Resmaa Menakem. Williams is saying that he remained aware of his body sensations in a mindful way so that he could steward his nervous system's response to this situation and not get carried away into a fight-or-flight response. When you stay in your body, you may sense tension rising, feel your stomach tighten, notice that your cheeks are getting hot, etc. Just noticing these helps you get some emotional distance from the situation so that you can respond calmly.

Comment: So, is it an example of African-American Vernacular English, then?

Comment: No, it's more jargon from people who study embodiment, somatics, trauma in the nervous system, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it as "I remained composed" or "I was able to control/restrain my emotions".

This is just a creative expression, not everything people say has already been said. However, we do say: jump out of one's skin. So, if you don't jump out of your skin, you are actually "staying in your body". So, actually, he's very creative with language!

You don't get many hits because the usage has no currency. Of the three written instances of "[I stayed in my body](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20stayed%20in%20my%20body%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01wKhuUCNslRuQp2BdCkFu4TbPf2g:1617194913047&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW9cvCyNrvAhUO_7sIHVCwC50QpwUIJg&biw=1520&bih=706&dpr=1.25)" in Google Books, one has "in" in "scare quotes" (implying the writer knows it's a non-standard usage), and one seems to be a sci-fi context where people can switch between different bodies.

Comment: CW formed from comments